# Show that a continuous map $f:X \to Y$ sends path-components to path-components.

Tags: general-topology

> Show that a continuous map $f:X \to Y$ sends path-components to path-components.

The path components are defined to be the set of equivalence classes $\pi_0(X)=\{[x] \mid x \in X\}$ where $[x]=\{y \mid x \sim y\}$ and $x \sim y$ if and only if there exists a path from $x$ to $y$.

I also know that a continuous map sends paths to paths that is if $\gamma:I \to X$ is a path connecting $x$ and $y$ say $\gamma(0)=x$ and $\gamma(1)=y$, then composing we have that $f(\gamma(0))=f(x)$ and $f(\gamma(1))=f(y)$ which is a path from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$.

How can I tie this up with the path-components? What I think I should prove is that if $x \sim y$, then $f(x) \sim y$? That is if there exists a path from $x$ to $y$, then there exists a path from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$, but this is what I just concluded so I suppose it's not what we're after here?

Comment: If $\gamma $ is a path from $x$ to $y$ then $f\circ \gamma$ is a path from $f(x)$ to $f(y)$.

Comment: if $C$ is a path component in $X$, then for $u,v\in f[C]$, we have $u=f(x),v=f(y)$ for some $x,y\in C$ connected by some path $\gamma:[0,1]\to X$. Try to make a path from $u$ to $v$ using $f$ and $\gamma$ and conclude that $f[C]$ is a path component in $Y$.

Comment: Perhaps i am misinterpreting the formulation of the question, but i would say that the statement is wrong. Consider for instance $f:[0,1] \rightarrow [0,2]$, $f:x\mapsto x$, then $f([0,1])=[0,1]$ is path-connected, but it is not a path component of $[0,2]$.

Answer (score 1):

> Show that a continuous map $f:X \to Y$ sends path-components to path-components.

How should we understand that? Typically such statement means that if $C\subseteq X$ is a path component, then $f(C)\subseteq Y$ is a path component as well. But such statement is false. For example if $Y$ is path connected with at least two points then no constant function $X\to Y$ maps path components to path components. Even though these are continuous.

So the correct (or at least precise) formulation is:

> Show that if $f:X \to Y$ is continuous and $C\subseteq X$ is a path component, then $f(C)$ is contained in a path component of $Y$.

And that is rather straight forward, because path connected subsets are always contained in some path component (which is a maximal path connected subsets). And $f(C)$ is path connected, because $C$ is. It is even enough to assume that $C$ is path connected, not necessarily a path component.